# Не получается объединить SQL-запросы

Tags: mysql, sql

Необходимо вытащить одним запросом: IP-адрес, браузер, ОС, адрес с которого зашел первый раз, адрес на который зашел последний раз, количество просмотренных уникальных адресов, время, прошедшее с первого до последнего входа.

Получается вытащить и объединить всё кроме количества просмотренных адресов:

```
select F_IP_USER, browser, os, max(first_url) as first_url, max(last_url) as last_url, max(sum_time) as sum_time 
from (
select F_IP_USER, URL_HOME as first_url, null as sum_time, null as last_url from fiveattributes fn1 where time = (select min(fn2.time) 
from fiveattributes fn2 where fn1.F_IP_USER = fn2.F_IP_USER 
group by fn2.F_IP_USER)
UNION select f_ip_user, null as first_url, TIMEDIFF(MAX(time), MIN(time)) as sum_time, null as last_url 
from fiveattributes fn2 group by fn2.F_IP_USER
UNION select F_IP_USER, null as first_url, null as sum_time, url_quest as last_url 
from fiveattributes fn1 where time = (select max(fn2.time)
from fiveattributes fn2 where fn1.F_IP_USER = fn2.F_IP_USER
group by fn2.F_IP_USER)
) res 
JOIN threeattributes on f_ip_user=t_ip_user
group by f_ip_user
```

Отдельный запрос на поиск уникальных адресов работает, но он не стыкуется в общий.

```
select f_ip_user, COUNT(url_quest) 
from (
select f_ip_user, url_quest 
from fiveattributes 
union 
select f_ip_user, url_home from fiveattributes
) r 
group by f_ip_user
```

Моя попытка добавить количество уникальных адресов:

```
select F_IP_USER, browser, os, max(first_url) as first_url, max(last_url) as last_url, max(sum_time) as sum_time, max(count(unique_url)) as unique_url
from (
select F_IP_USER, URL_HOME as first_url, null as sum_time, null as last_url from fiveattributes fn1 where time = (select min(fn2.time) 
from fiveattributes fn2 where fn1.F_IP_USER = fn2.F_IP_USER 
group by fn2.F_IP_USER)
UNION select f_ip_user, null as first_url, TIMEDIFF(MAX(time), MIN(time)) as sum_time, null as last_url 
from fiveattributes fn2 group by fn2.F_IP_USER
UNION select F_IP_USER, null as first_url, null as sum_time, url_quest as last_url 
from fiveattributes fn1 where time = (select max(fn2.time)
from fiveattributes fn2 where fn1.F_IP_USER = fn2.F_IP_USER
group by fn2.F_IP_USER)
UNION select F_IP_USER, null as first_url, null as sum_time, url_quest as last_url, url_home as unique_url from (select f_ip_user, url_home from fiveattributes union select f_ip_user, url_quest from fiveattributes) g
) res 
JOIN threeattributes on f_ip_user=t_ip_user
group by f_ip_user
```

Comment: Без структуры таблиц сложно ориентироваться

Comment: Проблема оказалась, по большей части в синтаксисе. Вопрос решён.